# How to merge nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge

I have a list of nested dictionaries (python 3.9) that looks something like this:

```
records = [
    {'Total:': {'Owner:': {'Available:': {'15 to 34 years': 1242}}}},
    {'Total:': {'Owner:': {'Available:': {'35 to 64 years': 5699}}}},
    {'Total:': {'Owner:': {'Available:': {'65 years and over': 2098}}}},
    {'Total:': {'Owner:': {'No Service:': {'15 to 34 years': 43}}}},
    {'Total:': {'Owner:': {'No Service:': {'35 to 64 years': 64}}}},
    {'Total:': {'Owner:': {'No Service:': {'65 years and over': 5}}}},
    {'Total:': {'Renter:': {'Available:': {'15 to 34 years': 1403}}}},
    {'Total:': {'Renter:': {'Available:': {'35 to 64 years': 2059}}}},
    {'Total:': {'Renter:': {'Available:': {'65 years and over': 395}}}},
    {'Total:': {'Renter:': {'No Service:': {'15 to 34 years': 16}}}},
    {'Total:': {'Renter:': {'No Service:': {'35 to 64 years': 24}}}},
    {'Total:': {'Renter:': {'No Service:': {'65 years and over': 0}}}},
]
```

The levels of nesting is not always consistent.  The example above has 4 levels (total, owner/renter, available/no service, age group) but there are some examples with a single level and others with as many as 5.

I would like to merge the data in a way that doesn't replace the final dictionary like `update()` or `{*dict_a, **dict_b}` does.

The final output should look something like this:

```
combined = {
    'Total': {
        'Owner': {
            'Available': {
                '15 to 34 years': 1242,
                '35 to 64 years': 5699,
                '65 years and over': 2098
            },
            'No Service:': {
                '15 to 34 years': 43,
                '35 to 64 years': 64,
                '65 years and over': 5
            }
        },
        'Renter': {
            'Available': {
                '15 to 34 years': 1403,
                '35 to 64 years': 2059,
                '65 years and over': 395
            },
            'No Service:': {
                '15 to 34 years': 16,
                '35 to 64 years': 24,
                '65 years and over': 0
            }
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recursion is an easy way to navigate and operate on arbitrarily nested structures:

```
def combine_into(d: dict, combined: dict) -> None:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            combine_into(v, combined.setdefault(k, {}))
        else:
            combined[k] = v

combined = {}
for record in records:
    combine_into(record, combined)
print(combined)
```

```
{'Total:': {'Owner:': {'Available:': {'15 to 34 years': 1242, '35 to 64 years': 5699, '65 years and over': 2098}, 'No Service:': {'15 to 34 years': 43, '35 to 64 years': 64, '65 years and over': 5}}, 'Renter:': {'Available:': {'15 to 34 years': 1403, '35 to 64 years': 2059, '65 years and over': 395}, 'No Service:': {'15 to 34 years': 16, '35 to 64 years': 24, '65 years and over': 0}}}}
```

The general idea here is that each call to `combine_into` takes one dict and combines it into the `combined` dict -- each value that is itself a dict results in another recursive call, while other values just get copied into `combined` as-is.

Note that this will raise an exception (or clobber some data) if some of the `records` have disagreements about whether a particular node is a leaf or not!

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution: `res = NDict.from_list_of_dict(records).raw_dict`

Test:

```py
>>> from naapc import NDict
>>> records = [
...     {'Total:': {'Owner:': {'Available:': {'15 to 34 years': 1242}}}},
...     {'Total:': {'Owner:': {'Available:': {'35 to 64 years': 5699}}}},
...     {'Total:': {'Owner:': {'Available:': {'65 years and over': 2098}}}},
...     {'Total:': {'Owner:': {'No Service:': {'15 to 34 years': 43}}}},
...     {'Total:': {'Owner:': {'No Service:': {'35 to 64 years': 64}}}},
...     {'Total:': {'Owner:': {'No Service:': {'65 years and over': 5}}}},
...     {'Total:': {'Renter:': {'Available:': {'15 to 34 years': 1403}}}},
...     {'Total:': {'Renter:': {'Available:': {'35 to 64 years': 2059}}}},
...     {'Total:': {'Renter:': {'Available:': {'65 years and over': 395}}}},
...     {'Total:': {'Renter:': {'No Service:': {'15 to 34 years': 16}}}},
...     {'Total:': {'Renter:': {'No Service:': {'35 to 64 years': 24}}}},
...     {'Total:': {'Renter:': {'No Service:': {'65 years and over': 0}}}},
... ]
>>> a = NDict.from_list_of_dict(records)
>>> print(a)
{
  "Total:": {
    "Owner:": {
      "Available:": {
        "15 to 34 years": 1242,
        "35 to 64 years": 5699,
        "65 years and over": 2098
      },
      "No Service:": {
        "15 to 34 years": 43,
        "35 to 64 years": 64,
        "65 years and over": 5
      }
    },
    "Renter:": {
      "Available:": {
        "15 to 34 years": 1403,
        "35 to 64 years": 2059,
        "65 years and over": 395
      },
      "No Service:": {
        "15 to 34 years": 16,
        "35 to 64 years": 24,
        "65 years and over": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
>>> type(a)
<class 'naapc.ndict.NDict'>
>>> normal_dict = a.raw_dict
>>> type(normal_dict)
<class 'dict'>
>>> normal_dict is not a.raw_dict
True
>>>
```

Doc: https://github.com/eiphy/naapc